# SwiftUI: @StateObject init multiple times

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to optimize my SwiftUI app. I have a strange behavior with a ViewModel stored as a `@StateObject` in its View. To understand the issue, I made a small project that reproduces it.

`ContentView` contains a button to open `ChildView` in a sheet. `ChildView` is stored as property as I don't want to recreate it every time the sheet is open by user (this works):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @State private var displayingChildView = false
    private let childView = ChildView()
 
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            displayingChildView.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Display child view")
        })
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $displayingChildView, content: {
            childView // instead of: ChildView()
        })
    }
}
```

`ChildView` code:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("init() of ChildView")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.add()
            }, label: {
                Text("Add 1 to count")
            })
            
            Text("Count: \(viewModel.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

And its `ViewModel`:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var count = 0
    
    init() {
        print("init() of ViewModel")
    }
    
    func add() {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

**Here is the issue:**

The ViewModel's `init` is called every time user opens the sheet. Why?

As `ViewModel` is a `@StateObject` in `ChildView` and `ChildView` is only init once, I am expecting that `ViewModel` is also only init once.

I have read [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/stateobject-observedobject-differences/) that says that :

> Observed objects marked with the @StateObject property wrapper don’t get destroyed and re-instantiated at times their containing view struct redraws.

Or [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject):

> Use @StateObject once for each observable object you use, in whichever part of your code is responsible for creating it.

So I understand that `ViewModel` should stay *alive*, especially as `ChildView` is not destroyed.

And what confuses me the most is that if I replace `@StateObject` with `@ObservedObject` it works as expected. But it is not recommended to store an `@ObservedObject` inside a View.

Can anyone explain why this behavior and how to fix it as expected (`ViewModel` init should be called once) ?

**A possible solution:**

I've found a possible solution to fix this behavior:

a. Move the declaration of `ViewModel` into `ContentView`:

```swift
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

b. Change the declaration of `ViewModel` in `ChildView` to be an `EnvironmentObject`:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
```

c. And inject it in `childView`:

```swift
childView
   .environmentObject(viewModel)
```

That means it's `ContentView` that is responsible to keep the ChildView's ViewModel alive. It works, but I find this solution quite ugly:

- All future child Views of `ChildView` could get access to `ViewModel` through environment objects. But it's no sense as it should be only useful for its View.
- I would prefer declare a ViewModel inside its View instead of inside its parent View.

And this solution still doesn't explain above questions about `@StateObject` that should stay *alive*...

Comment: Don't use view model objects, we don't need them, that is what the `View` struct and `@State` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI initializes the @State variables when a view is inserted into the view hierarchy. This is why your attempt to keep the state of the child view alive by assigning it to a var fails. Every time your sheet is presented, the child view is added to the view hierarchy and its state variables are initialized.

The correct way to do this is to pass the viewModel to the child view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var displayingChildView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            displayingChildView.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Display child view")
        })
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $displayingChildView, content: {
            ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)
        })
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.add()
            }, label: {
                Text("Add 1 to count")
            })
            
            Text("Count: \(viewModel.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean all ViewModels have to be stored (as @StateObject) by the parent of View they are the ViewModel? (Don't know if my question is understandable ^^).

Comment: And with your solution, the init of `ChildView` is called everytime `count` var is edited. It is not really optimized, no?

Comment: Think in terms of life cycle.  The viewModel should be created and held in a permanent place.  In this case, `ContentView` isn't going anywhere, so it works.  Even better, pass it to `ContentView`.  As far as `ChildView()` being created every time it is presented, that is not a concern.  SwiftUI creates views all the time.  It's very efficient and for SwiftUI to manage.  Since your `ChildView` is no longer storing state, let it be recreated.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks!  
And another question: if `ViewModel` doesn't need to store data when `ChildView` is closed and reopened, do I still need to create it in `ContentView`? Or is there another way to store it in `ChildView` directly (as a `@ObservedObject` for example)?

Comment: That comes back to the question of life cycle.  If you want the viewmodel to be created each time the child view appears, then create it in the child view.  The rule of thumb is to use `@StateObject` where you create the object, and @ObservedObject to hold a pointer to an object that was created elsewhere (in parent for example).  Also, for this example, you could have created the counter in ContentView as a `@State` variable, and then passed it to `ChildView` as a binding with `ChildView(count: $count)`.

Comment: OK. So as a summary: that means the initial state I have explained in my question was the case where `ViewModel` is recreated each time `ChildView` appears and it is the right way to do it. On the other hand, if I want that `ViewModel` is not recreated each time, I have to store it in parent View and inject it to the child.

Answer (score -2):

Objects slow down SwiftUI, to use it effectively we need to forget about view model objects and learn value types, structs, mutating func, closure captures, etc. Here is how it should be done:

```
struct Counter {
    private(set) var count = 0
    
    init() {
        print("init() of Counter")
    }
    
    mutating func add() {
        count += 1
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    
    @State private var counter = Counter()
    
    init() {
        print("init() of ChildView")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                counter.add()
            }, label: {
                Text("Add 1 to count")
            })
            
            Text("Count: \(counter.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh ok. Do you have any articles that explain a bit more why we should not use objects anymore in SwiftUI, I am very interested? Anyway, your solution does not work as the count variable always go back to 0 each time I open the sheet. Event if its init is called once and I store `ChildView` as let property of `ContentView`. Strange.

Comment: I recommend Apples tutorials and wwdc videos. And I thought you wanted the sheet to have its own state. If not then move it up and pass binding down for write access or let for read only.

Comment: As you might think, my question's example was a simplified case. How do you do when your `Counter` struct is a lot more complex, as a ViewModel could be (lot of @Published properties and so on) ? They are all mutating and redraw the View each time?

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't draw anything it just inits View structs and calls body if the params are different from last time. This hierarchy is diffed from last time and the result is used to update UIView objects which then eventually draw as normal. You can improve performance of the diffing with small View structs.

Comment: Ok, you mean if I have a complex ViewModel, I should separate it as many different smaller structs ? It makes the code a lot complicated, no?

Comment: Separate it into to small View structs and remove the object completely. Once you learn it's not complicated.

Comment: I don't totally agree with that as some of my ViewModels are sometimes quite complex and have lot of code logics. Separate them in many structs seems complicated. But I will have a try and find some article about that approach.

Comment: Well you can remove all the string formatting code and use SwiftUI's automatic formatting